# Writing an Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a query that will display the largest number of movies rented by one member and it should also show the member's name.

This is what I have.

```
SELECT FIRST, LAST AS, COUNT(mm_rental.member_id) AS "MAXIMUM MOVIES"
FROM mm_member, mm_rental
WHERE mm_rental.member_id = mm_member.member_id;
```

But its not working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you define `not working`?

Comment: It tells me that my "SELECT FIRST,LAST" is not a single-group group function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [COUNT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm) is an aggregate function, you should use [GROUP BY](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html) in your query.

And you should using [JOIN](http://psoug.org/definition/JOIN.htm) syntax.

More : [Please use ANSI join syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618)

```
SELECT [FIRST], [LAST], COUNT(mm_rental.member_id) 
AS "MAXIMUM MOVIES" FROM mm_member JOIN mm_rental 
ON mm_rental.member_id = mm_member.member_id
group by [FIRST], [LAST];
```