# Writing a query to find MAX number in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am suppose to Write a query that will display the largest number of movies rented by one member and that member's name. Give the output column a meaningful name such as MAXIMUM NUMBER.

This is what I have.

```
select max(maximum_movies)
  from (select count(*)maximum_movies
        from mm_member join mm_rental on
        mm_rental.member_id = mm_member.member_id
        group by first, last);
```

I got the maximum number but the output should be like this.

```
First  Last  Maximum_movies
John   Doe   4
```

But the output is

```
Maximum_movies
4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are the columns `first` and `last`? names?

Comment: Those are the columns that hold the first and the last names of the members

Comment: This is not PL/SQL, This is SQL. Kindly change the tags and title

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a PL/SQL Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760896/writing-a-pl-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [analytic rank](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm#i1269223) this way. [Demo on Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fdcf/18)

```
select memberid,
       last,
       first,
       rental_count
from (
select m.mm_memberid memberid,
       m.mm_last     last,
       m.mm_first    first,
       count(*) rental_count,
       rank() over (order by count(*) desc ) as count_ranking
from mm_member m
inner join mm_rental r on m.mm_memberid=r.mm_memberid
group by m.mm_memberid,
         m.mm_last,
         m.mm_first
  )
where count_ranking=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
WITH CTE_CNT AS ( 
    SELECT first, last, COUNT(*) num
    FROM 
        mm_member 
            JOIN mm_rental ON mm_rental.member_id = mm_member.member_id
    GROUP BY first, last
),
SELECT cnt.first, cnt.last, maxrent.mx
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(num) as mx FROM CTE_CNT
    ) maxrent JOIN CTE_CNT AS cnt ON cnt.num = maxrent.mx
;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
select first,last, maximum_movies 
from mm_member join mm_rental on
        mm_rental.member_id = mm_member.member_id group by first, last where 
maximum_movies = (select max(maximum_movies) from (select count(*)maximum_movies
        from mm_member join mm_rental on
        mm_rental.member_id = mm_member.member_id group by first, last));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the select in only 1 step. It is not really a MAX you are looking for, just a COUNT of the joined table.

```
    SELECT TOP 1
    M.member_id
    , M.first
    , M.last
    , COUNT(R.*) MovieCount
    FROM mm_member M 
    JOIN mm_rental R ON  R.member_id = M.member_id
    GROUP BY M.member_id, M.first, M.last
    ORDER BY MovieCount DESC
```